# Caching data in each iteration of a for loop

Tags: c, memory

For example, I have the following for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        int a = i + j;
    }
}
```

where is the value of `i` in each iteration stored? is it automatically stored in the cache?

Comment: What cache are you referring to? Depending on the processor, compiler and options, `i` may not be stored in any memory at all and may just be in a register. It's not that clear exactly what you are trying to ask. In fact, the whole block of code is likely to be optimised out completely as the loop essentially does nothing because `a` only has a lifetime of one iteration.

Comment: Note that since `a` is never used, an optimizing compiler will probably remove i, j, a, and the whole loop from the compiled program.

Comment: As described in the answer below, the compiler could unroll the loops and stick hardcoded values for `i` and `j` into each calculation of `a`.  But since a isn't used anywhere the compiler could just delete the loops and the calculations and get the same result - if you want the calcuations to be done you need to do something with `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C language is specified by the C standard using an imaginary computer that literally does the things described in the C standard. In this abstract computer, defining `i` with `int i = 0` reserves some bytes in memory to hold the value of `i`. Throughout the loop, the value of `i` is in that memory. There is no cache specified for this abstract computer, just some sort of memory that is not physically described.

When a compiler translates the C program to assembly language, the C standard allows the compiler to create any assembly language that produces the same observable results that the abstract computer would. In the translated program, the value of `i` might be in memory, it might be in a processor register, or it might be removed from the program entirely if the compiler figures out a way to compute the same results without using `i`. If it is in memory, the processor might store it in cache too. For the most part, processors cache data from memory automatically, without direct intervention from the program.